# How to chose a fixed clipping_gradients value [caffe]

Tags: caffe, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In caffe.proto

```
  // Set clip_gradients to >= 0 to clip parameter gradients to that L2 norm,
  // whenever their actual L2 norm is larger.
  optional float clip_gradients = 35 [default = -1];
```

I am having trouble setting the clipping_gradient, I think it should be dynamic anyway but if we are to chose a fixed number, how should we chose it? Is caffe setting it to 35? What does it mean?? I have experimented with a number of fixed choices but I see not much of a difference. I understand the exploding gradients / gradient clipping concept in the broad sense, however I am not sure how I should chose a fixed number in the solver.

Comment: Default value of `clip_gradients` is `-1`. `35` is probably type index used for structuring data by protobuf.

Comment: I see, any idea on how to chose it or customize it for your model?

Answer (score 0):

You can print out the sum of the sum squared gradients for some iteration to get an idea about `clip_gradients`. This can be done this way:

```
net_->forward();
net_->backward();
const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& net_params = net_->learnable_params();
float sumsq_diff = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < net_params.size(); ++i) {
    sumsq_diff += net_params[i]->sumsq_diff();
}
std::cout<<"sum of gradient: "<<std::sqrt(sumsq_diff)<<"\n";
net_->update();
```

For details about how `clip_gradients` is used see `solver.cpp`.